# Set temporary variable and reuse it further down in pug template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to pass along some values from my nodejs/express backend into the template (using *res.render({...})*), store it in some variables, then pass it further up until the front end (The usecase is that I need to do some mild calculation on the passed values and stored them in some intermediate variables)

I know I can do this in the pug file

```
block append script
  script.
    const foo = parseInt(#{stat.get('fooStat')}, 10);
```

But then later it seems that I can not refer to this later in my pug template, say here

```
  span #{foo}
```

The value is empty, I guess because it is undefined... What's the usual way to accomplish that.

Comment: I'd recommend that you carefully think about doing this, we have found that it's usually better to do this sort of thing in the route (or a model sitting inside the route) instead of pushing data logic into the template.  I'm not trying to second-guess your requirements, just pass along lessons we've learned along the way.

Comment: I eventually did what you advise, but still I want to solve this problem in that case I need to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the period after the `script` tag signals to pug that its contents should be treated as plain text. This is handy when you want to write javascript for client-side consumption, but any variables declared are inaccessible to pug.

```
script.
  const foo = 10;

span #{foo} // foo is undefined here
```

If you want to define a variable that pug can use later in the template, do so using [unbuffered code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html).

```
- const foo = 10

span #{foo} // renders <span>10</span>
```

Comment: It seems that when doing that, I cant later attach the variable (here `foo`) to the windows object for further consumption by the client side JS (say by writing something like `window.localNamespace.foo = foo` )

Comment: @zebullon you can, you just have to do it within a `script.` block and use interpolation to render the value of the Pug variable into the client-side javascript text